# List Box enable/disable one column

Tags: ms-access

Access 2007:  Is it possible to enable/disable one column in a List Box on a form.  For example: Say you have 2 columns A,B - If Me.A = title Then Me.B.Enabled = True Else  Me.B.Enabled = False.

If so, where would it go? On Got Focus, On Click??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by *disable*, but you can hide a column by adjusting the  [ColumnWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224077%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

So if you wanted to hide column2:

```
Me.MyListBox.ColumnWidths = (1 in;0;1 in)
```

And to hide column1:

```
Me.MyListBox.ColumnWidths = (0;1 in;1 in)
```